# Codewars (Haskell random testing QuickCheck)

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I have this working code in the random testing part of a Kata:

```
it "handles randoms " $ 
      property $ \x y -> updateHealth x y == if y > x then 0 else x-y
```

But I wanted the function signature to use Num, but when I did that I get an error because (I believe) it doesn't know how to generate Nums (as it doesn't know what kind of Nums to make?). I just hard set the type to Double as a work around.

However is there a way to use Quickcheck when your function signature uses Nums? Do you have to tell it specifically to generate random Int, or Integer, Float or Double?

Comment: `Num` is not a type; it is a typeclass, i.e. a collection of types. As such, you must specifiy a specific type to use. There is no way around this, because the compiler cannot choose a specific instance of `Num` to use (in most cases; see: monomorphism restriction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However is there a way to use Quickcheck when your function signature uses Nums? Do you have to tell it specifically to generate random Int, or Integer, Float or Double?

As @AJFarmar states, `Num` is a type class (family of types), not a specific type.

You CAN use QuickCheck with a function like `Num a => a -> a -> a`, you just have to specialize the type through annotation. You can either annotate the `updateHealth` function or else annotate the property function itself:

```
it "handles randoms " $ 
  property $ \x y -> (updateHealth :: Int -> Int -> Int) x y == if y > x then 0 else x-y
```

(or)

```
it "handles randoms " $ 
  property ((\x y -> updateHealth x y == if y > x then 0 else x-y) :: Int -> Int -> Bool)
```

These options are preferable to changing `updateHealth`'s type at its definition; you want your functions to stay general, so you can specialize them at their call sites if necessary.